The Powers of the President and military aid - giving away nuclear weapons
Suppose the president of the United States ha a meeting with the head of Russia and the head of the Ukraine. He told both individuals that they should sign the peace treaty he prepared. He also tells both sides that if they do not sign the US will supply a large number of weapons to the side that does not sign. Those weapons will include at least 50 long range missiles armed with thermonuclear warheads. The head of the Ukraine is willing to sign, the head of Russia is not. At this point, the head of the Ukraine asks the president to make good on his promise. Can the president legally deliver the weapons he promised without the consent of congress?

Yes and no

In practice, though, individual presidents’ guidance has generally reflected the notion that “the executive branch, after complying with the terms of applicable U.S. law, principally contained in the AECA [Arms Export Control Act], is free to proceed with an arms sales proposal unless Congress passes legislation prohibiting or modifying the proposed sale,” according to the Congressional Research Service.

Nuclear materials are one of the areas where Congress has legislated quite extensively what is and is not permitted. I believe that the transfer of actual nuclear weapons is prohibited.
So, what if a President, knowing that, decides to do it anyway? Well, it wouldn't be lawful, but it wouldn't be something the President could be prosecuted for because Presidents have absolute immunity for any action that falls within their official powers: giving assistance to an ally does that.
As a practical matter, the President can't physically transfer the weapons and not just because he's a relatively frail old man who would struggle to carry one - they are held in secure military bases and have pretty sophisticated anti-tamper mechanisms. So, to accomplish this, he would have to give an order to a general, who would have to order a colonel, who would order a major and so on down the line unit it reached the actual guys who know how to get things done. Any of those people could, and perhaps should, refuse the order on the grounds that it's an unlawful order.
Of course, for a serving military person to disobey an order is a very serious step and is likely something the courts would need to sort out. On the other hand, so is breaking a clear black letter law; while the President has immunity, that doesn't extend to anyone else. I'm not going to guess how this would play out.

transfer of nukes to German troops was part of the war plans in the cold war.

While the President is immue to prosecution, he could probably be impeached for something like this, couldn't he? Assuming the Congress and Senate stand their ground on the illegality of the delivery, that's even likely to succeed.

"while the President has immunity, that doesn't extend to anyone else." Tge Preaident does, however, have the power of pardon. Presumably he'd be willing to use it if he orders people to do something against the law.

@nick012000 indeed, and, arguably, he can do that before the crime is committed.

Nuclear Sharing
The US stores (presumably) 100 nuclear weapons in five NATO countries for use by their air forces. This is called NATO nuclear sharing. The plans are that those weapons would remain under US control right until use, if that should ever happen. But at some point, the USAF would hand armed nuclear weapons to allied air forces.
Doing so in peacetime would violate not just US domestic law but also the Non-Proliferation Treaty which the US has signed and ratified. Doing so in wartime would also violate the NPT, but by then the NATO states would not really care. The level of peacetime preparations for wartime handover has been argued to violate the NPT, and it has been argued to be permissible because no weapons are actually handed over.
The political effect of nuclear sharing is to spread the responsibilty (or blame) for NATO nuclear strategy to more governments, and to entangle more NATO forces with US nuclear forces -- a widespread conventional attack e.g. on the Belgian air force would put NATO nuclear forces under attack.
But it was generally understod that the US would also be held responsible for any use of these weapons, and that the use had a dual key -- weapons release by the US under US procedures, delivery system release by the host nation under host nation procedures. Compare the Cuban Missile Crisis, where the US made clear that they would blame the Soviets for any nukes launched from Cuba.
Politically, the plan you talk about is absurd. One side already has nuclear weapons, so this pretense of even-handedness falls flat.

Yeah, this plam would just prompt Russia to start launching nukes.
